# Loop through every field of object in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
const [checkboxes,setCheckkoxes] = React.useState({

    circular: Number(params.has('circular')?params.get('circular'):0),
    lei:Number(params.has('lei')?params.get('lei'):0),
    parecer:Number(params.has('parecer')?params.get('parecer'):0),
    decreto:Number(params.has('decreto')?params.get('decreto'):0),
    emenda:Number(params.has('emenda')?params.get('emenda'):0),
    instrucaoNormativa:Number(params.has('instrucaoNormativa')?params.get('instrucaoNormativa'):0),
    lei:Number(params.has('lei')?params.get('lei'):0),
    orientacaoNormativa:Number(params.has('orientacaoNormativa')?params.get('orientacaoNormativa'):0),
    leiComplementar:Number(params.has('leiComplementar')?params.get('leiComplementar'):0),
    ordemInterna:Number(params.has('ordemInterna')?params.get('ordemInterna'):0),
    parecer:Number(params.has('parecer')?params.get('parecer'):0),
    comunicado:Number(params.has('comunicado')?params.get('comunicado'):0),



})
```

I have this object, each of these field correspond to a value 0 or 1. I would like to know if any of them is one  without having to sum them up manually. How do I loop through each of these fields summing their values up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `some`. Get an array either by calling `Obejct.entries(checkboxes)` or hard coding yourself the properties’ array. Then you iterate with some.

The advantage of using some is also that if one element meets condition it stops the iteration.

Example:

```
if(Object.entries(checkboxes).some(([k, v])=>v===1){
  // conditional code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method Object.entries() to essentially convert your object into an array of the values and then loop through them using either a map function or a foreach loop.

Example
const arrayOfValues = Object.entries(checkboxes);

arrayOfValues.map(value => //Do something);

See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Note that value is actually an array itself containing property name as first element and value as second element.